# Error 500: Internal Server Error when viewing jobs in any project

Tags: postgresql, rundeck

I am getting a `Error 500: Internal Server Error` when trying to view jobs in any project.

**Extended error**:

```
URI
/project/tools/jobs
Class
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
Message
null
Caused by
ERROR: relation "scheduled_execution_filter" does not exist Position: 596
```

```
Line | Method
->>   96 | doFilter          in org.springframework.security.web.jaasapi.JaasApiIntegrationFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    193 | doFilter          in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder
|   1626 | doFilter . . . .  in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain
|     36 | doFilterInternal  in org.rundeck.grails.plugins.securityheaders.SessionIdChangeFilter
|    117 | doFilter . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    193 | doFilter          in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder
|   1626 | doFilter . . . .  in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain
|     -1 | call              in javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter$0
|     47 | defaultCall . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray
|     -1 | call              in javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter$0
|     67 | doFilterInternal  in org.rundeck.grails.plugins.securityheaders.RundeckSecurityHeadersFilter
|    117 | doFilter          in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
```

Any suggestions on where to look for the issue?

Comment: Hi! More context is needed. Can you add the full service.log output? Which Rundeck version are you using? Is it an upgraded instance? If so: did this happen after the upgrading process? If so: Old Database version? What kind of environment?

Comment: This was solved by matching versions. Good to close.